# pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_ce

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, active-directory, pyodbc

I am getting below error. Can anyone help me with the fix?

```
driver:ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;SERVER=ACE2T21978SQ001.az.3pc.att.com;DATABASE=QE2S_LASA01;UID=ITSERVICES\m53132;PWD=Dallastexas+6;Trusted_Connection=yes;TrustedServerCertificate=yes;Encrypt=yes;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_table_import.py", line 50, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:subject name does not match host name] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Tried connecting to SQL Server with Windows Integrated Authentication/MS Active Directory Authentication from Linux VM using Python

Comment: Do SQL server machine and client (python) match ODBC Driver version?
I tried downgrading to ODBC 17 and everything worked out

Answer (score 0):

The correct connection string attribute is `TrustServerCertificate=yes`, not `TrustedServerCertificate=yes`